# Hardy’s work about zeta function

Tags: zeta-functions

G.H.Hardy proved that zeta function have infinite root that is 1/2+bi.
I tried to find the paper including the proof but I couldn’t. Is there anyone who have the paper and can share it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Titchmarsh book.  He reports on Hardy (1914)  in section 10.2,  pages 256-258,  pdf 133-134:

[https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/EM18/TitchmarshZeta.pdf](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/%7Ezeilberg/EM18/TitchmarshZeta.pdf)

[image]

[image]

Apparently the first proof of infinitely many zeros on the critical line:

Hardy 1914, pages 1012  - 1014

https://archive.org/details/ComptesRendusAcademieDesSciences0158/page/n1013/mode/2up?view=theater

Hardy writes that he had an earlier announcement in the Proceedings of the London Mathematical Society, in 1914 and, I guess, presented to the Society on 12 March. They do archive the Proceedings but I haven't yet found the exact spot.

1917 or 1918:

https://projecteuclid.org/journalArticle/Download?urlId=10.1007%2FBF02422942

1921:

https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN266833020_0010?tify=%7B%22view%22:%22info%22,%22pages%22:%5B293%5D%7D

..

1914 again:
[image]

[image]

[image]